# Creating a captive portal for iPhone personal hotspot

Tags: iphone, hotspot

So I've read that the two things that determine a captive hotspot for Mac OS devices are of they can reach an Apple DNS served as well as Apple.com with a correct user agent.

However my goal is to create a captive portal that works on my iPhone (so if users connect to my open personal hotspot network they are prompted either my captive portal). Is this possible?